# How to handle exception and prevent crashing app

Tags: android

I am using the Amazon AWS SDK to download images from S3. Occasionally, when an image is not found an exception "AmazonS3Exception: Status Code: 404" is thrown. However, this seems like an exception which should not crash the app. How can I handle this exception so that it does not crash the app? Apologies, Im a noob to Java & Android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To follow up on type-a1pha's answer:

If you want to handle an exception gracefully, you would use a try-catch statement. It works something like this:

```
try {
    // Here you put the code that may throw an exception
} catch (AmazonS3Exception e) {
    // Looks like we errored out, log the exception and
    // tell the user that we 404'd
    Log.e(TAG, "Error fetching file from Amazon S3", e);
    Toast.makeText(context, "Error 404 while fetching file: file not found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    // Insert any other code you need here to recover from the error
} finally {
    // Note that the finally part is optional but useful if you want
    // to do something after the try-catch statement is finished
    // for example, if you were using an inputStream:
    inputStream.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
try{
    //code throwing exception
} catch (AmazonS3Exception) {}
```

Comment: maybe clarify the exception handling and show that you can log the exception gracefully